# Passport expiry date for entering Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, japan

I hear some countries require that you have at least 6 months before the expiry date on your passport from the date you enter (or possibly the date you intend to leave).

Is there a limit on passport expiry date for entry into Japan?

If it makes a difference, I have Australian and British passports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japan does not require the six months.

> Any foreign visitor who wishes to enter Japan must have a passport,
>   which will remain valid during the period of stay.

from http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/arrange/essential/visa.html . There are numerous less-official surces stating it even more explicitly, and statements from people who asked an embassy directly.

Answer (score 1):

No such requirement applies here. Your passport simply must be valid for the duration of your stay in Japan.

According to the [UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/japan/entry-requirements) for your British passport: "Your passport should be valid for the proposed duration of your stay. No additional period of validity beyond this is required."

According to the [Consulate-General of Japan--Melbourne](http://www.melbourne.au.emb-japan.go.jp/consular/visa/faq.html): "The passport must remain valid during the period of the stay but there is no minimum period of validity required."

Answer (score 1):

According to [timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) which the airlines use to check passport and visa validity, either your UK or Australia passport just needs to be valid on arrival.