Travelling back to UK with ~ 3months left on EU passport
Swedish passport holder, with Indefinite Leave to Remain in the UK. My passport will expire on March 4, 2025. Some countries demand 6 months left (but three months for EU)[1]. I think that if I travel (to Sweden) and return to the UK before December 3 (so more than three months left on my passport) I should be okay?
I queried this with border security in Sweden (they will always let me enter, whether my Swedish passport is valid/expired) and at Heathrow departures (who will let me travel to Sweden, assuming I have got more than 3 months left on my passport). Obviously, the former is no good for me if a book a flight for say December 10 and Heathrow prevents me from getting on that flight.
I noted the question (wrong country) and answers regarding entering Japan[2], especially timatic[3]. With timatic I tried both with the details travelling to my destination, and separately my return. However, I cannot find explicitly information regarding whether it's 3 months or 6 months going back to the UK.
[1] See bullet 1:
https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/tips/2024/07/16/?anchor=abroad&utm_source=MSE_Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_term=16-Jul-24-1e0787fd07c437aac32-6696c676a28ac1238c3017df6ffa8b5b&source=CRM-MSETIP-1e0787fd07c437aac32&utm_campaign=nt-highlights&utm_content=2#abroad
[2] Passport expiry date for entering Japan
Specifically
https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/tips/2024/07/16/?anchor=abroad&utm_source=MSE_Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_term=16-Jul-24-1e0787fd07c437aac32-6696c676a28ac1238c3017df6ffa8b5b&source=CRM-MSETIP-1e0787fd07c437aac32&utm_campaign=nt-highlights&utm_content=2#abroad[3] https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/69417/175248
i.e. timatic:
(https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC)
-- Edit --
Just to clarify that by "Heathrow", I asked an employee of the airline in question at the departure desks. So the answer came from the airline, not the airport itself.

Are you sure that heathrow won't let a citizen travel to their country of nationality if their passport has less than 3 months left? That seems odd, especially as the answer states, you could enter UK with less than 3 months left on your passport.

Your first link applies to UK citizens (and other non-EU citizens). EU citizens can enter the EU at any time at least up to the end of validity of the passport.

@ave Heathrow won't stop anyone from flying.  An airline operating from Heathrow (or anywhere) won't normally let passengers fly to the Schengen area with a non-EU, non-Schengen passport having less than three months' validity because the destination country won't normally admit such a traveler and will fine the airline a few thousand euros for bringing them with inadequate documents.

@phoog sure, but 1) question states heathrow said this 2) question implies that this applies to everyone, not just non-union citizens/residents.

The UK doesn’t have a ‘valid X months after entry / exit’ rule. Visitors are required only to have a passport valid for the whole length of stay. As you have ILR, you are not a visitor, and your passport is fine.
Source: Entering the UK

This is the correct answer. Like the OP I reside in the UK with ILR. My mum who still lives in my country of origin got hospitalised while my passport was within its last few months. I too was panicked. It took a few phone calls to seek consultation, but in the end I left and re-entered the UK with no problems. Mum is fine now btw.

For travel to Sweden:

There is never any minimum validity to travel to your own country. Those minima are for visitors, not citizens. So you can travel to Sweden (and the rest of the EU) up to the last day of validity.
Beyond that (once the passport is expired), you can most probably enter Sweden, but the airline may not let you board, and other EU countries may have issues as well. Time to get a new passport.

See Traveller's answer for travel to the UK.
